# Querying Servers

Tags: java, php, c++

I want to query few game servers.

I have made a server refresher in Java which queries each server in a loop one by one.

Will changing to C++/C or PHP make querying faster or should i stick to Java ??

UDP Packets are sent / received to query a server.

Also, is there any faster way to do this other than one by one in loop.

Worst case time(when all servers offline ) is  200ms X number of servers . (2s is timeout for each). which becomes large when server list is huge.

Comment: Query them all at once instead? And isn't 2s 2000ms or am I missing something.

Comment: It won't be a solution, so I will rather add it as a comment. Node.js was built for such concurreny and event handling in mind. You can have a look at it too.

Comment: Akshat Goel, Erlang is probably a pretty good candidate as well, if you want to pick a new language for the problem. It's not event-driven, but it's very good at massive concurrency. I don't think that's necessary for this problem, though.

Comment: Read about Node.js and will learn it now. Thanks.
Hope it does not have any problems with UDP packets .      
I had made it in java(for querying )->MySQL (for Storing all info) and GWT at frontend earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not gain anything by switching language. Since network I/O is your main bottleneck you should consider doing the querying concurrently. Use threads or a threadpool to query multiple servers at once.

Comment: I was going for Node.js but read this -> [link](http://teddziuba.com/2011/10/node-js-is-cancer.html)    . Also for start my webpage will be on hostgator which queries MySQL DB. Java standalone exe queries servers and updates MySQL DB . Any help where should i look for threadpool etc for UDP packets

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you could speed this up:

1. Use **C** instead, which can be slightly faster **if** you know how to write good C code.
2. Add **multi-threading** by querying multiple servers at the same time.
3. Use **multiple servers** (e.g. VPSs) from different continents and use those to query the gameservers closest to them. This will significantly decrease the latency.

Comment: I don't think the latency is the main problem for this. The timeout is for detecting *offline* servers, which won't answer anyway. It should be possible to query at least a few thousand servers in a couple of seconds from a single machine by adding concurrency.

Comment: You're probably right, but using C and multiple servers could improve it as well - I'm just trying to provide all options.